# MyBatis returns a List and doesn't want to return an object

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I want to retrieve data from PostgreSQL database using MyBatis 3.
I wrote this mapper inperface:

```
package datamodel.gis.building;
public interface BuildingMapperBatis
{
    // List of objects within rectangular box
    public List<BuildingDbDto> getByBBox( @Param("lat1") BigDecimal lat1,
                                          @Param("lon1") BigDecimal lon1,
                                          @Param("lat2") BigDecimal lat2,
                                          @Param("lon2") BigDecimal lon2 );

    // Retrieve the object by id
    public BuildingDbDto getById( @Param("id") Long id );
    /// public List<BuildingDbDto> getById( @Param("id") Long id );
}
```

The class BuildingDbDto is a trivial DTO object with private fields, public getters, no setters and a constructor initializing all the fields.

A piece of the MyBatis XML configuration is:

```
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="Building" type="datamodel.gis.building.BuildingDbDto" />
    </typeAliases>
    <environments default="default">...here is the connection specified...</environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="datamodel/gis/building/BuildingMapperBatis.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

The XML configuration of the mapper in the file "/src/main/resources/datamodel/gis/building/BuildingMapperBatis.xml" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="datamodel.gis.building.BuildingMapperBatis">
    <resultMap id="BuildingMap" type="Building" >
        <id column="bld_id" property="id" />
        <result column="bld_geo_latitude" property="latitude" />
        <result column="bld_geo_longitude" property="longitude" />
        <result column="bld_addr_settlement_name" property="addrSettlementName" />
    </resultMap>
    
    <select id="getByBBox" resultMap="BuildingMap">
        SELECT bld_id, bld_geo_latitude, bld_geo_longitude, bld_addr_settlement_name
        FROM get_buildings_in_bbox( #{lat1}, #{lon1}, #{lat2}, #{lon2} )
    </select>
    
    <!-- <select id="getById" resultMap="Building"> -->
    <select id="getById" resultType="Building">
        SELECT bld_id, bld_geo_latitude, bld_geo_longitude, bld_addr_settlement_name
        FROM get_buildings_in_bbox( 0,0,90,90)
        WHERE bld_id = #{id}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Then I perform the queries:

```
BuildingMapperBatis mapper = sessionFactory.openSession().getMapper( BuildingMapperBatis.class );
List<BuildingDbDto> found = mapper.getByBBox( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 );
BuildingDbDto dto = mapper.getById( id );
/*///
BuildingDbDto dto = mapper.getById( id ).get(0);
*/
```

The method getByBBox does work.

The method getById throws the exception at the line ".getById( id );":
"java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class datamodel.gis.building.BuildingDbDto from class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getById(Unknown Source)"
I tried both resultType="Building" and resultMap="Building", and the result is the same.

I tried to replace that lines of code to the commented out ones. I changed the result type of getById to a list and took the 0'th element of the list.
In this variant the code works correctly. But I don't like this conversion, because a search by id always returns only one (or none) object.

How can I make the method to return a single object, not a list?

Comment: Have you tried to specify `LIMIT 1` in your `getById` query?

Comment: Yes, but this didn't help. The query is correct, it always returns one record because it searches data by the primary key.

Comment: Try setting `getById` to `resultMap="BuildingMap"`.. Can't find anything else that looks unusual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem, so I answer my qustion.

The cause of exception was that I didn't declare BuildingDbDto as public class. I wanted to hide the DTO from business layer and made it package-protected. My intention was to transform the DTO into a buisness entity (containing data getters and methods for a business-logic) within the same package, and make the buisness entity public.

Unfortunately, the magic inside MyBatis must have an access to returned value classes, so DTOs have to be public.